# Visual Studio Code - Node.js TypeScript intellisence is not working

Tags: node.js, typescript, visual-studio-code

i created a new blank node.js app with Visual Studio Code and TypeScript. 
But i have the problem that the intellisence for the node types is not working in my TS File. I installed the tsd paketmanager to get the node.d.ts but VS code tell me only in my js files about the node objects.

For example the "http" module in my app.ts
[image]

and here in generated my app.js
[image]

What could be wrong in my configuration?

Thanks for any hints!

Regards